# ¿Como puedo obtener un texto de un textbox y mostrarlo en un label de otra Ventada C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo la duda de como poner el texto que se introduzca en un textbox en otra ventana.

Explicando esto:

El usuario se logeara en una ventana, al momento de dar ingresar se abrirá un splash dando la bienvenida, lo que quiero hacer es que aparezca el nombre de usuario que introdujo en el splash dando la bienvenida.

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Ventana de Login**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnIngreso_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Validacion de usuario y contraseña
            if (txtuser.Text == "User" && txtpass.Password == "1234")
            {
                //Si el usuario es correcto, llamar al splash
                SplashBienvenida splashBienvenida = new SplashBienvenida();
                splashBienvenida.LUser = txtuser;
                splashBienvenida.Activate();
                splashBienvenida.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //Mostrar el mensaje en caso erróneo 
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario o contraseña no validos");
            }

    }
```

**Ventana del Splash**

```
public partial class SplashBienvenida : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer dT = new DispatcherTimer();

    public SplashBienvenida()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        //Inicia el conteo que durara la ventana de Bienvenida
        dT.Tick += new EventHandler(dT_Tick);
        dT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
        dT.Start();


    }
    //Al momento que termine el conteo mandara llamar la ventana siguiente
    public void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Opciones opciones = new Opciones();
        opciones.Show();

        dT.Stop();
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como lanzas el splash? porque de eso depende que solucion sea la mas facil para lo que estas haciendo

Comment: Crea un constructor que reciba el nombre en tu formulario de "splash" y al crear el formulario, le pasas ese parámetro.

Comment: Pero ya le estas pasando el nombre al splash... no termino de comprender

Comment: No veo donde defines `LUser`. Pero si, si defines esa propiedad como pública, puedes posteriormente usarlo en el `Splash`

Comment: Es lo que no comprendo yo también, porque cuando lo ejecuto, no me muestra nada el nombre de usuario en el splash, solo el Label que agregue dando la bienvenida pero sin el nombre de usuario

Comment: Pero entonces...`LUser` que es, un label en el formulario? Lo declaraste como public?

Comment: Si es así, el problema probablemente es que debes pasarle la propiedad text: `splashBienvenida.LUser.Text = txtuser.Text;`

Comment: Muchas gracias Pikoh, era eso lo que me hacia falta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo creo que el problema es que estás asignando la referencia de TextBox al Label, cuando en realidad deberías asignar el valor contenido en el control.

O sea, deberías cambiar esto:

```
splashBienvenida.LUser = txtuser;
```

Por esto:

```
splashBienvenida.LUser.Content = txtuser.Text;
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Gracias Gustavo